# Problems in stopping/restoring Aircrack session

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, aircrack-ng

I'm running `aircrack-ng` version 1.6 on Live Kali. I noticed that "recently" a `-N` option has been added for saving a session, which can be later resumed with the option `-R`.
However this seems to have the following issues:

- the created session file is 0 bytes long
- almost always, I'm unable to stop (quit) aircrack e.g. trying `q` or `Ctrl-C` does noting and I have to `pkill` the process

How to solve this?